# How to get a cell and the immediate cell below it in a table

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, vlookup

Is there a way that I can get all the cells that contain "Student" along with the cell that's below it and put it in another table next to each other?

Maybe this picture will illustrate my problem better:
[image]

The main problem is to simply look in a column all the cells that contain "Student" and get the cell right below it too (discard everything else).

Will the best approach be to use `VLOOKUP()` or the `SEARCH()`, I'm struggling to create a formula for this small task. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just HSTACK two filters, the second with and offset range:

```
=HSTACK(
    FILTER(A3:A17,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Student",A3:A17))),
    FILTER(A4:A18,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Student",A3:A17))))
           ^^^^^^Note the offset
```

[image]

With irregular spacing:

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, but how would you apply it if the list was longer (50 students) and the Countries below each "Student" cell are not all exactly 4, but can vary. Some are just 2, some are 6, etc. How would I filter all these extra countries out and get only the immediate one below Student.

Comment: It does not matter.  It will return the line with student and the line directly under that.  It does not matter how many are between student as long as it is at least one.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on your previous thread, I can update the formula's if needed but I am guessing this example above is just an example?

This will require a helper column to my understanding, in order to trim out the fat.

**B1**

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(A1:A1000,NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("titanium",A1:A1000)))*NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("beagle",A1:A1000)))*NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("legend",A1:A1000)))*NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A1000,FIND(".",A1:A1000)-1))))),FILTER(A1:A1000,NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("titanium",A1:A1000)))*NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("beagle",A1:A1000)))*NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("legend",A1:A1000)))*NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A1000,FIND(".",A1:A1000)-1)))))<>0),"")
```

**C1** Required to be dragged down for X number of cells

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT($B$1:$B$1000,LEN($B$1:$B$1000)-FIND("/",$B$1:$B$1000)),LEN(RIGHT($B$1:$B$1000,LEN($B$1:$B$1000)-FIND("/",$B$1:$B$1000)))-1),$B$1:$B$1000),IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT($B$1:$B$1000,LEN($B$1:$B$1000)-FIND("/",$B$1:$B$1000)),LEN(RIGHT($B$1:$B$1000,LEN($B$1:$B$1000)-FIND("/",$B$1:$B$1000)))-1),$B$1:$B$1000)<>0),ROWS(C$1:C1)*2-1),"")
```

**D1** Required to be dragged down for X number of cells

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT($B$1:$B$1000,LEN($B$1:$B$1000)-FIND("/",$B$1:$B$1000)),LEN(RIGHT($B$1:$B$1000,LEN($B$1:$B$1000)-FIND("/",$B$1:$B$1000)))-1),$B$1:$B$1000),IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT($B$1:$B$1000,LEN($B$1:$B$1000)-FIND("/",$B$1:$B$1000)),LEN(RIGHT($B$1:$B$1000,LEN($B$1:$B$1000)-FIND("/",$B$1:$B$1000)))-1),$B$1:$B$1000)<>0),ROWS(D$1:D1)*2),"")
```

B1 will filter the data, and cells C1 and D1 will strip out the text you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Yeah the one above was a sample, I'll try to test this one, thanks

Comment: Hi Kevin, in the first formula B1. It filters out all cells except octane, not just the cells containing "beagle" "titanium" and "legend"

Comment: Interesting, the B1 formula should be filtering anything that contains the words "beagle", "titanium", "legend", and any cell where the first two characters are a number. It is working in my example but perhaps your values include different results that what I gathered from the image. Please note that Scott's answer is probably a much cleaner approach, and relevant to this specific question.

Comment: Oh, that's it :/ It shouldn't filter where the first two characters are a number, I'll be using those ones too

Comment: Replace B1 with `=IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(A1:A1000,NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("titanium",A1:A1000)))*NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("beagle",A1:A1000)))*NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("legend",A1:A1000)))),FILTER(A1:A1000,NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("titanium",A1:A1000)))*NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("beagle",A1:A1000)))*NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("legend",A1:A1000))))<>0),"")`

Comment: If that works, please be sure to mark Scotts answer as the correct one. I just had this answer prepared already.

Answer (score 0):

I know am late to the party, but you can try this something along the lines using `TAKE()`, `TRANSPOSE()` & `WRAPCOLS()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C3`

```
=TAKE(TRANSPOSE(WRAPCOLS(A3:A17,5)),,2)
```

---

**Note:** This works if the spacing is consistent.

---

For Irregular Spacing using `XLOOKUP()`, `FILTER()` & `HSTACK()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H3`

```
=LET(_Student,FILTER(F3:F17,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Student",F3:F17))),
HSTACK(_Student,XLOOKUP(_Student,F3:F17,F4:F18)))
```

---